# Adding components string to RequestHandler in Solr(with or without SolrNet)

Tags: c#, solr, solrcloud, solrnet

The idea is to Add Spellcheck Component string element to RequestHandler dynamically without using different handlers.

My RequestHandler in Solrconfig.xml looks like:

```
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="wt">xml</str>    
      <int name="rows">10</int>   
      <str name="qf">Content</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">false</str> 
    </lst>

    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck_DocName</str>
      <str>spellcheck_Content</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

So, how can the following elements dynamically in Request inside the element "arr" ?

```
  <str>spellcheck_DocName</str>
  <str>spellcheck_Content</str>
```

thanks for any proposal or idea in advance.

Comment: Have you seen the `update-requesthandler` command in [the reference guide section about the Config API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/config-api.html#commands-for-handlers-and-components)?

Comment: thank you for the feedback, but the idea is to add the elements in the component inside the RequestHandler dynamically (just like extra parameters) without changing the existing one.

Comment: If you just want to enable a registered component through the URL, I think you can use the name of the component with the value `true` as the argument - `spellcheck_DocName=true`? But if you want it to be enabled for all requests through the request handler (but define which ones are enabled dynamically), the config api is the way to do it.

Comment: thanks again for answer, but it is not possible , I tried it.